# How do I include grenades and other throwables for a modern D&D campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, d20-modern

I am currently making a zombie apocalypse/dystopia campaign.  I have made all of the armor, weapons, creatures and rules, but I don't have enough grenades. How do I fit grenades into my D&D campaign? :)

PS: Yes I know I shouldn't use D&D, so please don't mention this.

Comment: I've closed this as primarily opinion-based. This seems to be mostly a matter for people coming up with arbitrary ideas, or a discussion prompt, but we don't handle questions of that nature. Check out our [tour] to get an idea of how we work here -- we're a Q&A site and we're focused on questions that can have a single best or correct answer. Instead you can ask a question like this on a forum, [such as one of these we've gathered a list of here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/).

Comment: @doppelgreener There are rules (optional) for grenades and firearms in the DMG (we used muskets in my nephew's campaign)  which is why I asked about the DMG in my comment.  There is also the Artificer UA already posted ... on the other hand, I see your point.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast If it's more of a "where can I find rules for grenades?" that's pretty reasonable, though as posed it seems to be also asking for ideas for "enough grenades" or ideas for how to add grenades into a campaign, in terms of narrative or placement or usage or whatnot, which is pretty open-ended itself.

Comment: Have you checked into the [Unearthed Arcana](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana) articles at the WoTC website?  Do you have a copy of the Dungeon Masters Guide?

Comment: @doppelgreener No reason not to leave on hold until various bits are clarified, per your action already taken.